# Finding point of inflection on a Bézier Curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives, bezier-curve

I need to determine the first point of inflection on a Bézier curve, if it exists, for a computer graphics application. My original idea was to iteratively walk the curve, evaluating 2nd derivatives until it reached the end, or the magnitude of the 2nd derivative was at a maximum, but someone advised me that I could calculate the inflection points directly.

Is there a closed mathematical solution to find the inflection point?

Comment: Well, the [Bernstein polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) that are used in defining your Bézier curves admit simple expressions for their derivatives. If you're using cubic Bézier curves, you can use the fact that the second derivative of a cubic function is a linear function...

Comment: @J.M. unfortunately the curves can have an arbitrary number of control points and so can be of any degree.

Comment: If the degree is arbitrary, then in general there won't be a "closed form" for your inflection points; you will definitely have to use numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm definitely no maths expert (and will probably be having lots of questions to ask here) but have been recently investigating this very same thing so I'll just re-post what I posted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12465160/1503120):

To determine the points of inflection on a bezier, find the time or times in the interval (0, 1) [excluding the endpoints of course] for which the cross product of the first and second derivatives of the parametric equation of the bezier is zero i.e. $f' \times f'' = 0$.

This is noted in various sources like [this page](http://www.caffeineowl.com/graphics/2d/vectorial/cubic-inflexion.html) and p 4 of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.8080&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: That's called a determinant, written $\det(f', f'')$ or $|f' \; f''|$.  The term cross product is used for something else (usually in dimension three or seven).

Comment: Hey thanks for your clarification on the terminology. I agree -- cross product is a vector, so I should really call this a determinant.